# ASP.net : debug on a 32 bits machine, release to 64 bits

Tags: asp.net, 32bit-64bit

I have to transform a python web application into an ASP.net application. Problem is that I will be developing on a Windows XP Pro 32 bits, and will be publishing to a Windows Server 2003 64bits. The application is to make use of a MySql database.

Am I asking for troubles by doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem. Just make sure you build your app for Any CPU. If you use [MySQL Connector for .Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), which is a 32-bits DLL, your Application Pool must be enabled to run 32-bits applications, which you can configure on IIS.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine.
Check the properties of your web app (and any other referenced projects you compile).

```
Properties -> Build -> Platform: should be set to: Any CPU.
```

This is the default, so unless you have changed it, you will be ok.

AnyCPU assembly's will be JITed to 32 or 64 bit code depending on the process they are running in.
You typically only need to mess with this if you are referencing unmanaged dll's.

Answer (score 1):

As Visual Studio is a 32-bit application, ASP.NET development is usually performed in a 32-bit environment. You won't be able to develop using any 64 bit assemblies (like the Azure assemblies, for example), but unless you need to do that it probably won't make any difference.

Comment: I don't think that is quite right. By default asp.net apps target 'Any CPU'. I run a 64 bit machine, so my asp.net apps run as 64 bit when run locally. Refer to my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure which bit "isn't quite right"? VS's web server [is 32-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837285/how-to-utilize-webdev-webserver-exe-vs-web-server-in-x64), so even on a 64-bit machine, if you use that you're developing in a 32-bit environment.

Comment: indeed Cassini and IIS Express are currently 32 bit only. Did not know that. Good to know.